# Related Drop down lists in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, combobox

I want to create two related drop down lists! (Combobox)
The first list contents name of all Provinces & the second list contents name of all Cities of selected Province at the first list! All data, come from database which works correct.
In coding, everything looks right, but when I select a province, the second list contents nothing! I wonder what's wrong with my code?!

Any help or clue, would be greatly appreciated!

here is my code in php::

```
<?php
connect();  
echo '<label for="Province">Province:</label>';                                     
$Province = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT(Province) FROM Provinces"); // Run your query
echo '<select name="Province" id="Province">'; // Open your drop down box
echo  '<option value="SelectProvince" >Select<Province/option>'; 
// Loop through the query results, outputing the options one by one
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($Province)) {
echo '<option value="'.$row["Province"].'">'.$row["Province"].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';// Close your drop down box                    

echo '<label for="City">City:</label>';
$City = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT(City) FROM Provinces WHERE Province
= '$_POST[Province]'");
echo '<select name="City" id="City">'; // Open your drop down box
echo  '<option value="SelectCity" >SelectCity</option>';
// Loop through the query results, outputing the options one by one
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($City)) {
echo '<option value="'.$row["City"].'">'.$row["City"].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';// Close your drop down box
@mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Is this all the code? There is nothing there to "link" the select boxes. Do you have any Javascript, is there a form?

Comment: $_POST[Province] should be `=".$_POST['Province'])` but this should be asked by ajax or?

Comment: if you add a submit button and post this to the server it should work or give you an error that can be addressed